# 3 Field SUMS but only when there is value

Tags: php, mysql, sum

this is probably going to be a no brainer. I have tables

game:

```
guid(PK), puid, gScoreA, gTimesPlayed, gScoreB.
```

player:

```
puid(PK), pFname, pLname
```

I am trying to:

```
Select 
    player.puid, 
    (SUM(game.gScoreA)/SUM(game.gTimesPlayed)) as skillA, 
    (SUM(game.gScoreB)/SUM(game.gTimesPlayed)) as skillB 
FROM 
    player, 
    game 
WHERE 
    player.puid = game.puid 
ORDER BY 
    skillA DESC, 
    skillB DESC
```

so per game a player could have either `gScoreA` OR `gScoreB` and ALWAYS a `gTimesPlayed`. So I want all of `SUM(game.gScoreA)` divided by only `SUM(game.gTimesPlayed)` where `game.gScoreA` has value and `game.gScoreB` does not and vice versa for `SUM(game.gScoreB)` / `SUM(game.gTimesPlayed)` WHERE `gScoreA` has no value - as a total for each player in the player database... smoke and steam from my ears!!

Comment: I think your query should give you the desired resultset, but you will have to add a `GROUP BY player.puid` just before ORDER BY

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    player.puid, 
    SUM(game.gScoreA)/SUM(IF(game.gScoreA IS NOT NULL, game.gTimesPlayed, 0)) as skillA, 
    SUM(game.gScoreB)/SUM(IF(game.gScoreB IS NOT NULL, game.gTimesPlayed, 0)) as skillB 
FROM player INNER JOIN game ON player.puid = game.puid 
GROUP BY player.puid
ORDER BY 
    skillA DESC, 
    skillB DESC
```

Use `GROUP BY` to get a result per player.

Also, use the `JOIN` syntax instead of comma-style joins.